# dpkg: warning: while removing directory /usr/local not empty so not removed

Tags: debian, dpkg

I built and installed a debian package from the following folder structure:

- myprog

  - DEBIAN

    - control
  - usr

    - local

      - bin

        - myprog.sh

... using the following commands:

> dpkg -b myprog/ myprog.deb && dpkg -i myprog.deb

When i now remove the package by typing:

> dpkg -r myprog

.. I got the following warning:

> dpkg: warning: while removing myprog, directory '/usr/local' not empty so not removed.

As I think this is an every day scenario, how can I avoid the warning?

Greets Thorsten!

### # Edit

I tried to install the file to /bin instead of /usr/local/bin and got no warning when removing it. Seems so, that the /usr/local/.. folder will not treated as a system folder (?) by dpkg.

Comment: See answer to this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021002/my-deb-file-removes-opt/58066154#58066154

Answer (score 10):

That's right -- packages should never touch `/usr/local` directory, [it's reserved for system administrators](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) by Filesystem Hierarchy Standard and is their zone of responsibility.

Comment: Well, some packages create entries under /usr/local, to better organize what admins can add there (say, Python related, TeX, ca-certificates).

In at least one case (ca-certificates), the README.Debian suggests, if we want locally-created packages to provide new trusted certificates (say, for internal CAs), to deploy the files under /usr/local/share/ca-certificates. Which is OK, in the end, as it is something *LOCALLY* created, but it creates problems if you decide to remove the package afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the warning, according to [this post](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2006/03/msg00242.html), is to create a "core-custom"/dummy package, which will install in /opt, and be required by your main package.

So, when you'll uninstall your main package, at least your dummy package will be left in /opt and dpkg will not issue the warning.

You can also use that dummy package as a meta-package to install all the regular packages you like.